# Can I mix different data transformations for different variables in the same dataset?

Tags: pca, data-transformation

Can I mix different data transformations for different variables in the same dataset?
Target analysis: Principal Component Analysis.

Comment: can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: @gunes for example, can I use log transformation on some variables and square root transformation on other variables in the same dataset?

Comment: Please [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=transform*+regression+mix) for (very) closely related discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the mathematics of Principal Component Analysis that prohibits the use of different transformations on diferent of the input variables. So you can do it. If it makes sense depends on details of the actual application you did not tell us.